# SB_THUMBTRACK is not sent repeatedly

Tags: c, winapi

MSDN says the following about `SB_THUMBTRACK`:

> The user is dragging the scroll box. This message is sent repeatedly
>   until the user releases the mouse button. The HIWORD indicates the
>   position that the scroll box has been dragged to.

However, I am only getting this message once (when I click on the scroll box).

This is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

HWND hEdit;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_HSCROLL:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == SB_THUMBTRACK)
        {
            // Display some text
            SendMessage(hEdit, WM_CHAR, 'a', 0);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WinClass";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    //--------------------------------------------

    // Create Window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "WinClass", "My Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 200, 200, 500, 300, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Create horizontal Scrollbar
    CreateWindowEx(0, "SCROLLBAR", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE| SBS_HORZ, 50, 50, 300, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Create Edit control
    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 10, 10, 250, 21, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Show Window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    //--------------------------------------------

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you do not set the scrollbar info, the system could not calculate the track position.

After setting the scrollinfo,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")



HWND hEdit;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_HSCROLL:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == SB_THUMBTRACK)
            {
                int i = 0; 
                char buf[3];
                _itoa_s(HIWORD(wParam), buf, 3, 10);
                SetWindowText(hEdit, buf);
            }
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "WinClass";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    //--------------------------------------------
    InitCommonControls();
    // Create Window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "WinClass", "My Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 200, 200, 500, 300, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Create horizontal Scrollbar
    HWND hScroll = CreateWindowEx(0, "SCROLLBAR", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SBS_HORZ, 50, 50, 300, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Create Edit control
    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 10, 10, 250, 21, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    SCROLLINFO si = {0};
    si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    si.nMin = 0;
    si.nMax = 100;
    si.nPage = 10;
    si.nPos = 0;
    si.nTrackPos = 0;
    SetScrollInfo(hScroll, SB_CTL, &si, true);

    // Show Window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    //--------------------------------------------

    MSG msg = {0};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

everything should work well.